# Get original entry value in LogQL line_format

Tags: grafana-loki

In LogQL `line_format` template expression, is there a way to access the original log entry (assume the entry is not in JSON or any parseable format and all labels are log labels and not extracted labels).

example:
`... | line_format "{{.log_label1}}, {{.log_label2}}: {{<some way to show the entire original log entry>}}"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way it to prepend it with a regular expression capturing the entire message

`... |regexp '(?P<message>.*)' |line_format "{{.some_other_var}} {{.message}}"`

> Note that the ' around the regex should really by ` otherwise it might not work

Comment: The regexp is a nice trick, thanks! I wonder if there is some "default" variable that would allow the same without involving another parser...

Comment: Yup, I was wondering that too and then found your question :) sadly the documentation is not really that good , though it is a great product

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [line template function](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/template_functions/#__line__):

```
... | line_format "{{.host}} {{ __line__ }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like instead of `regexp` you can use `json` parser:

```
... | json | line_format "{{.stream}}: {{.log}}"
```